# Using JPA Entity Inheritance with IdClass Composite Primary Key involving Object references

Tags: jpa, composite-primary-key, object-reference

I am trying to use IdClass composite primary keys giving the following scenarios:

- Primary keys involve object reference (entity objects)
- Entity object in primary key are foreign keys to other entities (has OneToOne or ManyToOne mapping)
- The entity classes having composite Ids have subclasses

Here are the entity classes concerned:

Contract.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ContractPK.class)
@Table(name = "CONTRACT")
public abstract class Contract implements Serializable {
     private FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement;
     private CrudeType crudeType;

     public Contract() {}

     public Contract(FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement, CrudeType crudeType) {
        this.fiscalArrangement = fiscalArrangement;
        this.crudeType = crudeType;
     }

     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     public FiscalArrangement getFiscalArrangement() {
          return fiscalArrangement;
     }

     public void setFiscalArrangement(FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement) {
         this.fiscalArrangement = fiscalArrangement;
     }

     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     public CrudeType getCrudeType() {
         return crudeType;
     }

     public void setCrudeType(CrudeType crudeType) {
         this.crudeType = crudeType;
     }
    //equals and hasCode
}
```

ContractPK.java

```
public class ContractPK implements Serializable {
    private FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement;
    private CrudeType crudeType;

    public ContractPK() {}

    public ContractPK(FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement, CrudeType crudeType) {
        this.fiscalArrangement = fiscalArrangement;
        this.crudeType = crudeType;
    }
  //getters and setters
}
```

RegularContract.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REG")
public class RegularContract extends Contract{}
```

AlternativeFundingContract.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("AF")
public abstract class AlternativeFundingContract extends Contract{   
    private Double sharedOilRatio;
    private Double terminalPeriod;
    private Double terminalSharedOil;
    //getters and setters
}
```

CarryContract.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CA")
public class CarryContract extends AlternativeFundingContract {}
```

ModifiedCarryContract.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MCA")
public class ModifiedCarryContract extends AlternativeFundingContract{}
```

Forecast.java

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ForecastPK.class)
@Table(name = "FORECAST")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FTYPE")
public abstract class Forecast implements Serializable {
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private Contract contract;
    //other non-primary properties       

    public Forecast() {}

    @Id
    public Integer getPeriodYear() {
        return periodYear;
    }

    public void setPeriodYear(Integer periodYear) {
        this.periodYear = periodYear;
    }

    @Id
    public Integer getPeriodMonth() {
        return periodMonth;
    }

    public void setPeriodMonth(Integer periodMonth) {
        this.periodMonth = periodMonth;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    public Contract getContract() {
        return contract;
    }

    public void setContract(Contract contract) {
       this.contract = contract;
    }

    //other getters and setters   
}
```

ForecastPK.java

```
public class ForecastPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private Contract contract;

    //getters and setters
}
```

RegularForecast.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REG")
public class RegularForecast extends Forecast {}
```

AlternativeFundingForecast.java

```
Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("AF")
public abstract class AlternativeFundingForecast extends Forecast {
   //properties 
}
```

CarryForecast.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CA")
public class CarryForecast extends AlternativeFundingForecast{}
```

ModifiedCarryForecast.java

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("MCA")
public class ModifiedCarryForecast extends AlternativeFundingForecast{}
```

Controller class: JvForecastController.java

```
@Named(value = "jvProdController")
@SessionScoped
public class JvForecastController implements Serializable {
    @Inject
    private JvForecastServices forecastBean;     
    private Forecast currentProduction;   
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private FiscalArrangement currentFiscalArrangement;
    private Contract currentContract;

    public JvForecastServices getForecastBean(){
        return forecastBean;
    }

    public void currentContractChanged() throws Exception {
        if (currentContract instanceof RegularContract) {
            currentProduction = new RegularForecast();
        } else if (currentContract instanceof CarryContract) {            
            currentProduction = new CarryForecast();
        } else if (currentContract instanceof ModifiedCarryContract) {
            currentProduction = new ModifiedCarryForecast();
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Undefined contract type");            
        } 

        //set primary key fields
        currentProduction.setPeriodYear(periodYear);
        currentProduction.setPeriodMonth(periodMonth);
        currentProduction.setContract(currentContract);
    }

    public void productionVolumeChanged() {
        getForecastBean().enrich(currentProduction);        
    }

}
```

Bean implementation class: JvForecastServicesImpl.java

```
@Dependent
public abstract class JvForecastServicesImpl<T extends Forecast> extends    CommonServicesImpl<T> implements JvForecastServices<T>, Serializable {
    public JvForecastServicesImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public T computeOpeningStock(T forecast) {
        Forecast prod = getPreviousMonthProduction(forecast);
        //some code
        return forecast;
    }

    @Override
    public T getPreviousMonthProduction(T forecast) {
        int month = forecast.getPeriodMonth();
        int year = forecast.getPeriodYear();
        Contract cs = forecast.getContract();
        Contract contract = null;

        if (cs instanceof RegularContract) {
             contract = new RegularContract(cs.getFiscalArrangement(),    cs.getCrudeType());
        } else if (cs instanceof CarryContract) {
            contract = new CarryContract(cs.getFiscalArrangement(), cs.getCrudeType());
        } else if (contract instanceof ModifiedCarryContract) {
            contract = new ModifiedCarryContract(cs.getFiscalArrangement(), cs.getCrudeType());
        }

        FiscalPeriod prevFp = getPreviousFiscalPeriod(year, month);

        T f = find(new ForecastPK(prevFp.getYear(), prevFp.getMonth(), contract));

        return f;
    }

}
```

CommonServicesImpl.java

```
public abstract class CommonServicesImpl<T> extends AbstractCrudServicesImpl<T> implements CommonServices<T> {}
```

Implementation of the find() method in AbstractCrudServicesImpl.java

```
public abstract class AbstractCrudServicesImpl<T> implements AbstractCrudServices<T> {
protected final Class<T> entityClass;
    public AbstractCrudServicesImpl(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    //some CRUD methods  

    @Override
    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

When the following line of code in JvForecastServicesImpl class executes:

```
T f = find(new ForecastPK(prevFp.getYear(), prevFp.getMonth(), contract));
```

I get the error message:

> 10:24:59,492 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-42) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.contract.Contract
>   10:24:59,497 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-42) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component RegularForecastBean for method public abstract java.lang.Object com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.CommonServices.enrich(java.lang.Object): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.contract.Contract
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.forecast.jv.JvRegularForecastServices$$$view23.enrich(Unknown Source)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.controller.JvForecastController.productionVolumeChanged(JvForecastController.java:233)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
>       at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:459)
>       at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
>       at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:805)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.contract.Contract
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1689)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1619)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1106)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1033)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:213)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.impl.AbstractCrudServicesImpl.find(AbstractCrudServicesImpl.java:44)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.forecast.jv.impl.JvForecastServicesImpl.getPreviousMonthProduction(JvForecastServicesImpl.java:204)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.forecast.jv.impl.JvForecastServicesImpl.computeOpeningStock(JvForecastServicesImpl.java:47)
>       at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.forecast.jv.impl.JvForecastServicesImpl.enrich(JvForecastServicesImpl.java:112)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
>       ... 86 more

Comment: The PK class should not refer to Entity objects. It should refer to the PK of those Entity objects. See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA calls this type of composite primary key a "derived identity".

You will need to change your `IdClass`es. `ContractPK` should look something like this (assuming `FiscalArrangement` and `CrudeType` have simple primary keys):

```
public class ContractPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer fiscalArrangement;
    private Integer crudeType;
    ...
}
```

Note the attribute names match the `Entity`'s `@Id` attribute names, but the types must match the types of the target `Entity`s' primary keys.

If the target `Entity`s use `@IdClass`es, `ContractPK` should look something like this:

```
public class ContractPK implements Serializable {
    private FiscalArrangementPK fiscalArrangement;
    private CrudeTypePK crudeType;
    ...
}
```

Note the attribute types are now `IdClass`es.

Likewise, `ForecastPK` should look something like this:

```
public class ForecastPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private Integer contract;
    ...
}
```

or this:

```
public class ForecastPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private ContractPK contract;
    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I actually tried both your suggestion and @NeilStockton's, by using the PKs of entity in my IdClasses. But I am now facing a new challenge: Eg. PK class ForecastPK refers to ContractPK, and in the target entity (Forecast) I defined the field "@Id ContractPK contract". When I build, I get the error: "BLOB/TEXT column 'contract' used in key specification without a key length". How should I map the PK field ContractPK in the target entity?

Comment: I don't think you need to make any changes to your original Forecast class. Leave Contract mapped like this: `@Id @ManyToOne public Contract getContract() {...}`

Comment: Ok great! I did define in my ForecastPK class the primary field ContractPK contract; and in the target entity class Forecast, i define private Contract contract; and '@Id @ManyToOne public Contract getContract(){..}'. It finally worked!!! Thanks a bunch. This is my first time trying StackOverflow, and I now believe in it. Thank you.